# After updating to Xcode 8 I get errors

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks

I get these errors in my xcode, after I updated to the newest xcode:

[image]

I am using firebase and swift, and the error is in myProjectTests.swift file? Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 0):

It's saying your frameworks are missing.  You probably just need to remove and re-import your frameworks.

Comment: Just tried deleting the facebook frameworks and re-importing them, but nothing has changed :(

Answer (score 0):

```
1.Quit your Xcode 
2.Restart your system 
3.Go to 
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData and
Delete this folder 
4.Clean your project 
5.Run
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it away by simply running Terminal and installing the pods again.